# "Absolute" version of determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, determinant, permanent

It is well known that for a matrix $A = (A_{i,j})$, the determinant of $A$ is

$$\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \mbox{sgn} (\sigma)\prod_{i \in [n]} A_{i,\sigma(i)}.$$

Is there any way to manipulate the matrix to obtain, or any existing interpretation for, the "absolute" version of the determinant, which is

$$\det^+(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i \in [n]} A_{i,\sigma(i)}?$$

Comment: That's called the [permanent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)) of a matrix

Comment: I'd add that there are some instances of the permanent that are easy to calculate... For instance, if you want to know the remainder of the permanent modulo $2^k$ for some $k$, that can be done in time $n^{k+3}$, where the permanent is calculated on an $n \times n$ matrix.  See this answer for details on how to do it: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37573/on-complexity-of-permanent-bmod-2t?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quantity $$\operatorname{perm}(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i \in [n]} A_{i,\sigma(i)}$$ is called the [*permanent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)) of matrix $A$.

Technically, the answer to "is there any way to manipulate the matrix to obtain" $\operatorname{perm}(A)$ is "yes": just go through all $\sigma \in S_n$, compute $\prod_{i \in [n]} A_{i,\sigma(i)}$ for each $\sigma$, and add these values up.

However, if you are asking if there is any *reasonable* way to do this, the answer is probably not. Computing $\operatorname{perm}(A)$ is [$♯P$-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete), which means there is no known polynomial-time algorithm, and good reason to believe one does not exist.

This remains true if the entries of $A$ are all either $0$ or $1$, which also leads to one of the important interpetations of $\operatorname{perm}(A)$. Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with $n$ vertices on each side; let $A$ record which edges $G$ has by setting $A_{ij} = 1$ if there is an edge between the $i^{\text{th}}$ vertex on the left side and the $j^{\text{th}}$ vertex on the right side, and $0$ otherwise. Then $\operatorname{perm}(A)$ counts the number of perfect matchings of $G$: the number of bijections $\sigma$ between the two sides with an edge between $i$ and $\sigma(i)$ for all $i$.

Comment: Readers may be interested in this article by Scott Aaronson about the permanent versus determinant, with applications to quantum computing: https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=2925